# Incrementing int counter with visibility

Tags: java, volatile, atomicinteger

I have a situation where one thread updates int and another one at some point reads it. So single-reader single-writer.
So far I was using `volatile` int for that purpose, but since this forces full sync on memory barriers I was thinking about something else.

One approach would be `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()`
but I think this has exactly the same effect and will actually be slower

Another approach would be to use `AtomicInteger.lazySet` with extra non-volatile counter for writer.
So basically we would have

```
private int counter;
public AtomicInteger visibleCounter = new AtomicInteger();

private void write() {
   counter++
   visibleCounter.lazySet(counter)
}

// called by reader
public int isCountEqual(int val) {
   return val == visibleCounter.get()
}
```

as a naive "`lazyIncrement`".

Would it be actually more performant than simple increment of `volatile` int by writer?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a very weird approach not to say very wrong, why do you need to do this? Do you have a perf issue in your application that is related to this?

Comment: So it's not an issue for you if reader reads an old value?

Comment: No, it's not  an issue as long as at some point 10ms etc I will get correct result i.e. val == visibleCounter

Comment: @Nicolas. Thread that is doing write is in a critical path and I would like to avoid any slowdown if possible

Answer (score 1):

If lazy increment is one of your options I'll suggest `LongAdder`. [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html)
`LongAdder` is good for multiple threads updates.

> ... under high contention, expected throughput of this class is significantly higher (than `AtomicLong`)

Comment: I should have mentioned. I'm still on Java 1.7 and I'm not sure if updating Long would be more performant than int